# How to make one side of border of square FrameLayout Draggable to make a rectangular one in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a constraint layout with child Framelayout with an image in it. Now I want to drag only left, right and bottom borders of the framelayout. How can i achieve this scenario?